# Why is debug_putstr() not being printed during boot?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, linux-kernel, grub2

I'm asking myself why `debug_putstr()` in [`arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.c#L414) is not being printed during x86 boot phase, though it is configured to do so with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`. On other systems it's being printed. Does this depend on the BIOS? Do some BIOSes don't have the ability to print in this phase?

Comment: It turns out when `set debug=all` in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is enabled, `debug_putstr()` is beeing printed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it depends on the video mode and zero page ([`struct bootparam`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/bootparam.h#L114), [documented here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/boot.txt), it also includes [`struct screen_info`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/screen_info.h#L10)) setup prepared by a bootloader (GRUB) and BIOS.  `bootparam` is passed to [`decompress_kernel()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.c#L369) as the first argument.

The actual function of `debug_putstr()` is [`__putstr()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.c#L173)  (Note that it's enabled [only when `CONFIG_X86_VERBOSE_BOOTUP` is set](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.h#L39)).  It prints messages by directly writing characters one by one on VGA text VRAM memory and I/O ports based on `screen_info`.  So it works only for VGA in the text mode.

You might want to look into `grub.cfg` to see which video mode is set (by [`gfxmode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/gfxmode.html)) when it hands over control to the kernel.